# NextJs 13 Middleware Parameters Per Endpoint

Tags: javascript, next.js, routes, middleware

I would like to add middleware with specific parameters to each nextjs endpoint individually as could be done using the /pages routing system before the /app router. Specifically to use a library to validate a request against a schema.

Previously, this could be done using:

```
const handler = (req, res) => {
  // endpoint code here...
}

export function validate(schema, handler) {
  // validate schema
  // return error if validation fails
  // execute handler(req, res) if validation passes
}

export default validate(specificSchemaName, handler)
```

`Validate()` would be the generic middleware and we can specify `specificSchemaName` per endpoint.

My question is how could this be achieved using the app router approach as NextJs recommends using the `middleware.ts` file in the root directory? Ideally I wouldn't need to specify a mapping per endpoint as it could get tedious.

I have attempted to use the same approach such as:

```
const handler = (....) => {
  // endpoint functionality
}

export function POST(schema, handler) {
  // middleware validation
}

export default POST(specificSchemaName, handler)
```

In order for the router the direct to the POST method, however the endpoint wouldn't accept the request.

**EDIT:** The following code works but is not ideal in terms of replication.

```
export async function POST(request: Request) {
  const schema = masterSchema;
  try {
    await schema.validate(await request.json());
  } catch (error) {
    return new Response(JSON.stringify(error), {
      status: 400,
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    });
  }

  return postHandler(request);
}

const postHandler = async (request: Request) => {
  console.log("POST handler", request);
  return new Response("POST handler", {
    status: 200,
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
  });
};
```